# How to make reactive input in RShiny?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I create an input value for data.R code?

ex:

UI.R

```
numericInput(inputId= "diametro", label= "Diametro do Aco:", value= 0)
```

Server.R

```
????
```

Data.R

````
    query <- 
  "select 
cod_ordem_producao as Ordem,
dim_ext_tubo as Diametro,
esp_par_tubo as Parede,
cod_aqa as AQA,
tmo_ciclo_plan as Ciclo,
dth_criacao_reg as Data,
dsc_aco as Grau,

val_lim_escoamento as LE,
val_tensao_residual as TR
from
QT_QTS.PLA_ORDEM_PRODUCAO

where diametro = **_THE INPUT VALUE FOR DIAMETRO HERE_**

order by DTH_CRIACAO_REG desc"

df <- dbGetQuery(
  connection_reportUser,
  query
)
df```
````

I could not create a reactive value for this.
The user will enter with a value of "diametro" in the numeric gadget, and the database will search for this in the data.

Thx for the help

Answer (score 2):

Another way is the `paste()` function. If you need a vector of inputs (more than one condition) you can use `paste0()` with `collapse` argument indicating the separator for pasting each element of the vector.

UI.R

```
numericInput(inputId= "diametro", label= "Diametro do Aco:", value= 0)
```

Server.R

```
library(RMySQL)
library(shiny)
getQuery <- reactive({
   query <- paste("select cod_ordem_producao as Ordem, dim_ext_tubo as Diametro, esp_par_tubo as Parede, cod_aqa as AQA, tmo_ciclo_plan as Ciclo, dth_criacao_reg as Data, dsc_aco as Grau, val_lim_escoamento as LE, val_tensao_residual as TR from QT_QTS.PLA_ORDEM_PRODUCAO where diametro = ",
   input$diametro,
   " order by DTH_CRIACAO_REG desc",
   sep="")

   df <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
   return(df)
)}
```

Comment: doesn't `paste` have the `collapse` argument?

Answer (score 0):

U need something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

df <- eventReactive(input$diametro,{
  connection_reportUser %>% dbGetQuery(
  glue::glue( "select 
        cod_ordem_producao as Ordem,
        dim_ext_tubo as Diametro,
        esp_par_tubo as Parede,
        cod_aqa as AQA,
        tmo_ciclo_plan as Ciclo,
        dth_criacao_reg as Data,
        dsc_aco as Grau,

        val_lim_escoamento as LE,
        val_tensao_residual as TR
        from
        QT_QTS.PLA_ORDEM_PRODUCAO

        where diametro = {input$diametro}

        order by DTH_CRIACAO_REG desc"
  )
  )
})
```